# Difference between に and で in e.g. 痛みに歪んだ顔

Tags: meaning

Do they both just state the reason, if not how are they different?

痛みに歪んだ顔 vs 痛みで歪んだ顔

Answer (score 2):

Both are natural, and they mean exactly the same thing. I somehow feel the former is slightly more literary or "refined", but I cannot explain why and other people may not agree with me.