# Particle に used to express reason/cause

Tags: grammar, particle-に

> 彼の落ち着いた態度**に**私の恐怖心は消えた。
> My fear disappeared thanks to his relaxed disposition. (given translation by duolingo)

The usage of に is confusing me in this sentence.　I would be happy with 態度のために or 態度のおかげで, but に on its own is not something I've seen used like this before.

Is this good grammar? Is it maybe more/less formal than the other two options? In what situations should I use に like this?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/72042/5010

Comment: See also: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/90818/5010 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/83466/5010 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/83880/5010